# Deleting from a table does not remove row

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, sql-delete

DISCLAIMER: I am aware of SQL Injection, I am getting the function done first.

My delete from button does not seem to remove my row in my SQL table

**products-one-time.php**
[image: 1]

This is the output of my foreach, the numbers below the delete button are the groupids, just to show they are unique.

this is the code for the delete button, it redirects to **clinics_buttons.vc.php** on click.

```
  <a href="clinics_buttons.vc.php<?php echo '?delete-coupongroup='.$rowCouponGroup['groupid']; ?>" onclick="return confirm('Delete this group?');">
    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm full_width" data-toggle="modal">
      <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>DELETE
    </button>
  </a>
  <?php echo $rowCouponGroup['groupid']; ?>
```

**clinics_buttons.vc.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

$routePath = "../";
require_once($routePath . "_config/db.php");
  $dbConfig = new config_db();
  $db = $dbConfig->init();

$delete_coupongroup = $_GET['delete-coupongroup'];

if (isset($_GET['delete-coupongroup'])) {
  $stmt = $db->prepare("DELETE FROM `product_onetime` WHERE groupid = $delete_coupongroup");
  $stmt->execute();
  header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
  }

?>
```

this is the product_onetime table

[image: 2]

What I see is that my code seems to look like they are connected, but the delete button does not work. I tried to manually do the SQL in phpmyadmin, for example:

```
DELETE FROM `product_onetime` WHERE groupid = 5
```

Doing it manually works, but the php/sql does not. Would like some input.

Comment: What debugging have you tried? Is `$delete_coupongroup` set (BTW you should really set this after you've checked the value is set).  Also your prepared statement isn't really a prepared statement, it should have bind parameters rather than having the value included in it.

Comment: I already mentioned I am trying to get the function working first before adding others like bind parameters and anti SQL injection. Also "$delete_coupongroup" has a value from the groupid in "products-one-time.php"

Comment: Try to do it with $_POST and do var_dump($_POST['delete-coupongroup']) to check  if the form was submitted successfully!

Comment: Can you add a `var_dump($delete_coupongroup);` inside `if (isset($_GET['delete-coupongroup']))`? Just to check if it really contains what you are expecting it to be

Comment: Why do you put a button inside a link? At least add `type=button` to the button so it doesn't submit a form and thereby reloads the page. Better don't use a button, but make the link look like a button using CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the file `clinics_buttons.vc.php` is not executed at all, because the code we see in the question is inside a `<form>`. In this case, the button behavior overrides the link behavior and the browser will submit the form instead of following the link.

You should be able to see that in the network tab of your development tools in your browser.

As a quick fix, change the button from a submit button into a push button:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm full_width" data-toggle="modal">
  <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>DELETE
</button>
```

A better solution would be not to use a button at all. Just make the link look like a button by using CSS styling. Or alternatively, remove the code from outside the outer form tag and give it its own form using clinics_buttons.vc.php as the form action.

Comment: yes, found out that the form tag is the issue, the rest of the code works perfectly